# Copy file with a lock on it

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

I have an application running on a server which is doing stuff and writing everything it does to a log file.
I also have secondary application which is kind of like a monitoring panel also running on the server but is a different process. What I would like to do is the following:

I would like my monitoring file to be able to copy the log file which currently has a lock on it from the other application and then email it to me.
I have tried using scp to connect to the server and copy it manually to my computer(and it did work), however I would like to be able to do that through my java monitoring application. And I have no idea where to start.

Comment: `I have tried using scp to connect to the server and copy it manually to my computer` Was this successful?

Comment: @copeg made an edit. Yes it was successful and didn't crash the main application writing to the log.

Comment: you can use `JSch` to do the same thing through your monitoring app instead of emailing it to yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried using scp to connect to the server and copy it manually to my computer(and it did work)

The [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library has a [ScpFrom](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpFrom.java.html) module that you can use to `scp` copy the data from the server to your computer or application. This can be done by one of the following:

1. Manually running the module (eg java -jar)
2. Copying the source of the module into your project and adding the JSch library to `classpath` (more programmatic control - preferred approach)
3. Using the library module programmatically eg `String[] args = {user@remotehost:file1" "localfile"}; SCPFrom.main(args);`

Comment: I want the monitoring software that is already on the server to do it. Is it possible, or do I have to now write a separate application to run on a separate computer in order to be able to connect and copy properly?

Comment: @Quillion, `want the monitoring software that is already on the server to do it. Is it possible `thanks for the clarification - you should be able to _ssh/scp_ to `localhost`. Seems like a bit overkill to do so, but if it works and is the only way to get around the file lock....

Comment: sounds like a valid answer with a pinch of insanity added in. If no one gives a better solution I will accept yours as the correct one within a day.

Comment: `with a pinch of insanity added in` Indeed